# How to export base64 encoded x.509 certificate with private key without using OpenSSL

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates, digital-certificate

I have a Root CA certificate with .cer extension with private key.
I have to Export that certificate as .pem extension with private key in base64 encoded format **without using OpenSSl**.
I am not able to do this with mmc.

Is there any tool or script available for converting certificate from pfx to pem format **without using openssl** in windows.

Please help me by sharing code or any scripts or commands etc...
Thanks...

Comment: Are you sure you want to export root CA certificate with private key?

Comment: yeah sure. Using mmc I tried to export my certificate,when I select Yes, export the private key radio button then in next step am not able to select Base-64 encoded X.509(.cer) option

Comment: Because Windows natively don’t support requested format. You can export to PFX/PKCS#12 from mmc and then have to use some tools or PowerShell script to convert it to your requested format.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Is there any tool available for converting pfx to pem format without using openssl in windows.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the window's `certutil` tool to encode a file to Base64. Try this command:

> certutil -encode {YOUR_PFX_FILE} {CONVERTED_FILE_NAME}

This command should put the appropriate certificate header too.

Comment: I tried this command but at the beginning and ending of a pem file it contains -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- some data  -----END CERTIFICATE-----                                                                                                  I think in existing file private key is not present. But I want pem file with private key also

Comment: @Prakash That is what PEM file will look like. It will have the header and footer. And it also contains the private key.

Comment: I tried with openssl command openssl pkcs12 -in input.pfx -out output.pem -nodes with this command pem file contains  -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----   data   -----END PRIVATE KEY----- and -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  data -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: The openssl is encoding the private key and the certificate(s) separately. Where as the certutil encodes the entire PKCS12 as pem format (keystore), which mean it will have the private key. The certutil doesn't change the format of the file, it only encodes as is. It depends on your use case if you want them separately or like an entire keystore.

Comment: My use case is I want them separately because my third party library reads the data between -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- . So how can I separate  them.